# The ratio of a .__ proto __ and b()

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance, prototype, prototypal-inheritance

The code contains

```js
let a= new b();
```

It follows from this equality that `a` is an instance of type `b`, since it was created using `new` and the constructor function `b`. On the other hand, `a .__ proto __ = b.prototype`, that is, `a` prototypically inherits `b.prototype`. That is, we get that `a` inherits `b` and `a` inherits `b.prototype` (prototype). This is true? Does `a` inherit `b`?

Comment: `a` is an object and `b` is something like a `class`, so there is nothing to do with inheritance in this case

Comment: "*`a` is an instance of an object of type `b`*" - no, `a` is simply an instance of "class" `b` (or type `b`, if you prefer). And by that statement we mean that `Object.getPrototypeOf(a) === b.prototype`. "*the object being created, of which `a` is an instance*" - there is no extra object involved, it's simply `a instanceof b`. If you mean the `b.prototype` object, that's not "being an instance of", that's just "inheriting from".

Comment: Short answer: No, `a` does not inherit `b`, meaning `b` is not in `a`'s inheritance chain. Yes, `a` does inherit `b.prototype`, meaning `b` is at the head of `a`'s inhertance chain. For completeness,  `a instanceof b` checks to see if `b.prototype` is anywhere along `a`'s inheritance chain.